# How to: Vue3 composition API plugin with component rendering (confirmation windows, toasts)

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to write several Vue3 plugins for my own usage via composition API.

Let's talk about the confirmation window plugin.

How I want to use it:

```
const confirm = inject('confirm');

async function handleDelete(item) {
    const isConfirmed = await confirm({ 
        title: 'Delete entity', 
        description: 'Are you sure you want to delete this entity?',
    });

    if (isConfirmed) {
        // Business logic / service call here
    }
}
```

It will be used many times in many components.

So, I create a folders `plugin -> confirm`.
Then I create 2 files:

index.js

```
import Component from './component';

export default {
    install(app, options = {}) {
        const handler = function(options) {
            // How to render imported component?
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                // Pass 'resolve' into component and resolve it with 3 values: true, false, null. 
                // Similar to click Yes, click No, close window.
            });
        };

        app.provide('confirm', handler);
    },
};
```

component.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-title">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="modal-body">{{ description }}</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button @click="handleConfirm">Confirm</Button>
        <button @click="handleReject">Reject</Button>
        <button @click="handleClose">Close</Button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Confirm',
        components: {
            Modal,
            Button,
        },
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            resolve: {
                type: Function,
            },
        },
        setup(props) {

            function handleClose() {
                props.resolve(null);
                // Remove somehow rendered dialog
            }

            function handleConfirm() {
                props.resolve(true);
                // Remove somehow rendered dialog
            }

            function handleReject() {
                props.resolve(false);
                // Remove somehow rendered dialog
            }

            return {
                handleClose,
                handleConfirm,
                handleReject,
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

Maybe anyone knows how to finish this plugin, or someone can suggest a better way for such plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many attempts, I figured out how to make it.

First of all, in the component, we return just one node. This helps us to simplify the code. So, the template of the component will be like this:

```
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-title">{{ title }}</div>
        <div class="modal-body">{{ description }}</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button @click="handleConfirm">{{ confirmText }}</Button>
            <button @click="handleReject">{{ rejectText }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in index.js, we import the required for rendering functions from vue.

```
import { createVNode, render } from 'vue';
```

After that, we should create VNode, pass props into the component (one of the props will be our resolve function), and render to some div.

When we rendered content, we attach it to the body. But before that, we put rendered node into a variable because, in the end, we must remove our node from the DOM.

And the final step - we remove the node from the DOM and return the result of a fulfilled promise to the caller.

Working example:

index.js

```
import { createVNode, render } from 'vue';
import Component from './component';

export default {
    install(app, options = {}) {
        const handler = async options => {
            let node = null;
            const container = document.createElement('div');

            const response = await new Promise(resolve => {
                const vm = createVNode(Component, {
                    ...options,
                    resolve,
                });
                render(vm, container);

                node = container.firstElementChild;
                document.body.appendChild(node);
            });

            document.querySelector('body').removeChild(node);

            return response;
        };

        app.provide('confirm', handler);
    },
};
```

```
<template>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-title">{{ title }}</div>
        <div class="modal-body">{{ description }}</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="primary" @click="handleConfirm">{{ confirmText }}</button>
            <button @click="handleReject">{{ rejectText }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Button from '@/components/ui/button';

    export default {
        name: 'Confirm',
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            confirmText: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Ok',
            },
            rejectText: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Cancel',
            },
            resolve: {
                type: Function,
            },
        },
        setup(props) {
            function handleClose() {
                if (props.resolve) {
                    props.resolve(null);
                }
            }

            function handleConfirm() {
                if (props.resolve) {
                    props.resolve(true);
                }
            }

            function handleReject() {
                if (props.resolve) {
                    props.resolve(false);
                }
            }

            return {
                handleClose,
                handleConfirm,
                handleReject,
            };
        },
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    }
</style>
```

Usage:

```
const confirm = inject('confirm');

async function handleDelete(item) {
    const isConfirmed = await confirm({ 
        title: 'Delete entity', 
        description: 'Are you sure you want to delete this entity?',
    });

    if (isConfirmed) {
        // Business logic / service call here
    }
}
```

And that's it, just add more style properties for your needs.